# glScissor behaving strangely in my code

Tags: opengl

A laptop user running an `ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series` just showed me a video of my 2D game running on his machine, and it would appear my `glScissor` code was not working as intended on it (despite it working on soo many other computers).

Whenever I want to restrict rendering to a certain rectangle on the screen, I call my `SetClip` function to either the particular rectangle, or `Rectangle.Empty` to reset the scissor.

```
public void SetClip(Rectangle theRect)
{
    if (theRect.IsEmpty)
        OpenGL.glDisable(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest);
    else
    {
        if (!OpenGL.glIsEnabled(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest))
            OpenGL.glEnable(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest);

        OpenGL.glScissor(theRect.Left, myWindow.clientSizeHeight - theRect.Bottom,
           theRect.Width, theRect.Height);
        CheckError();
    }
}
```

Is this approach wrong? For instance, I have a feeling that `glEnable` / `glDisable` might require a `glFlush` or `glFinish` to guarantee it's executed in the order in which I call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put my money on a driver bug. Your code looks fine.

The only thing I suggest changing this:

> ```
> if (!OpenGL.glIsEnabled(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest))
>        OpenGL.glEnable(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest);
> ```

into a mere

> ```
> OpenGL.glEnable(OpenGL.EnableCapp.ScissorTest);
> ```

Changing glEnable state comes practically free, so doing that test is a microoptimization. In fact first testing with `glIsEnabled` probably costs as much, as the overhead causes by redundantly setting it. But it happens that some drivers may be buggy in what they report by `glIsEnabled`, so I'd remove that to cut another potential error source.

> I have a feeling that glEnable / glDisable might require a glFlush or glFinish to guarantee it's executed in the order in which I call them.

No they don't. In fact glFlush and glFinish are not required for most programs. If you're using a double buffer you don't need them at all.

Comment: I'm in contact with the user, he ran `AMD Driver Autodetect` and it told him he had the latest driver, and is running Windows 7.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Yes. So what? Even the latest drivers can have bugs.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, the `glIsEnabled` was not just a performance concern, but the culprit also. Removing it fixed it, and I also found others who've done similar: [Explicitly save GL_SCISSOR_TEST to workaround driver bugs](https://github.com/MachineMuse/MachineMusePowersuits/pull/325)